# Toggle class on buttons in Svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte

Consider this Svelte code

```
{#each filters as filters, i}
   <div class='filter-container'>
      <div class='button filter' on:click={ () => setFilter(filters.name, filterContext)}>{filters.name}</div>          
   </div>
{/each}
```

The above filter buttons are made depending on how many filters there are in some js object. How can I create a class that is toggled for all filter buttons when the one button is clicked.

eg. when one is active all the others are not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Class are just strings - in svelte you can bind them to an expression as any other attribute.

For example:

```js
<div class={'button filter ' + (activefilter === filters.name ? 'isactive' : '')}/>
```

when `activefilter === filters.name` is true, then the button class will became `'button filter isactive'`

A special short syntax to toggle classes is provided too. Find more [here](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/classes)

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure I fully understand what is happening here though.  do i need to set the value of 'activefilter' to filters.name when I click it ? which is then used to evaluate if it has the class 'isactive' ?? :)

Comment: exactly! Just set activefilter = filters.name when you click it.

Comment: got it working! thanks again! :D Am really enjoying svelte! Just need to work out how to filter the js object now, using the spread operator.. i think ?!

Comment: well, you can use just plain ".filter()" javascript method on an array - example: mylist.filter(somecondition) 

use a watch expression for that
   
let mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4]  
$: filteredlist = mylist.filter( x => x > 2)

Answer (score 4):

We can easily bind class names to expressions, so that the class will be added if the expression becomes truthy:

```
<script>
    let isActive = false
</script>

<style>
    .active {
        color: red;
    }
</style>

<h1 class:active={isActive}>Hello!</h1>
<button on:click={() => isActive = !isActive}>Click me</button>
```

Here, clicking the button toggles the `isActive` boolean. The class `active` is bound to that variable on the `h1` element and you can see that the color now changes on every button click.

That is the standard way on how to set single classes dynamically.

REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/988df145876a42c49bb8de51d2cae0f2?version=3.23.0